# Google script - Need assistance on IF function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I used to work with multiple projects on 1 sheet to use multiple OnEdit events.
Now that the OnEdit events got more plenty and I have to many projects I need to group them in to one project.

Since I merged my code no longer works.

In one sheet I have 4 checkboxes.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C4"){
    Logger.log('C4 selected');
    FunctionC4();
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C5"){
    Logger.log('C5 selected');
    FunctionC5();
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C6"){
    Logger.log('C6 selected');
    FunctionC6();
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C7"){
    Logger.log('C7 selected');
    FunctionC7();
  }
}
```

So far this works great but when I then call my FunctionC4 (or any other) things stop working at my IF function

```
function FunctionC4() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var Range = sheet.getRange(4,3);
  var toggle = Range.getValue();
  Logger.log(toggle);
  if (toggle == "TRUE") {
    Logger.log('C4 is true');
    sheet.hideColumns(6, 15);
  }
  else if (toggle == "FALSE") {
    Logger.log('C4 is false');
    sheet.showColumns(6, 15);
    sheet.hideColumns(11, 1);
  }
}
```

My logger.log(toggle) still displays true or false. So I know toggle is either true or false and the function is called.
I don't understand why the IF function doesn't read it. I never get the logger.log "C4 is true" or false.

I'm guessing it has something to do with my `Range.getValue();` but after hours of searching I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) returns Google's interpreted value of the cell

> The value may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String depending on the value of the cell.

In this case, it will return a [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/boolean), not a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/string).

Try

```
if (toggle == true) {
  // ...
}
else if (toggle == false) {
  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could try `if (toggle == "true")`, but that only works because it's lowercase. It's equivalent to writing `if (toggle.toString() === "true")`, which is essentially what happens when you use [loose equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using).

Answer (score 2):

As a side note to Diego's answer. If you are planning to use the `onEdit(e)` function please modify your logic as follows to get advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). Pass the event object as an argument to each of the functions:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C4"){
    Logger.log('C4 selected');
    FunctionC4(e);
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C5"){
    Logger.log('C5 selected');
    FunctionC5(e);
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C6"){
    Logger.log('C6 selected');
    FunctionC6(e);
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C7"){
    Logger.log('C7 selected');
    FunctionC7(e);
  }
}
```

and then `FunctionC4` will be:

```
function FunctionC4(e) {

  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var toggle = e.value;
  
  Logger.log(toggle);
  if (toggle == true) {
    Logger.log('C4 is true');
    sheet.hideColumns(6, 15);
  }
  else if (toggle == false) {
    Logger.log('C4 is false');
    sheet.showColumns(6, 15);
    sheet.hideColumns(11, 1);
  }
}
```

and follow exactly the same logic for the other functions as well.

Note that `e.value` is "only available if the edited range is a single cell". Your code already assumes this to be the case with your existing conditions, e.g. `e.range.getA1Notation() == "C4"`.